# Alternativa3d Change Resolution for iOS in Flash Builder

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, 3d

I have a problem. I did the first example (Alternativa for dummies part I) and it runs fine but only fills 1/4 of the screen when using Air for iOS. How can I change the resolution?
Here is a screenshot:
http://tinypic.com/r/34yo86q/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this code to set up the camera?

```
camera.view= new View (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
```

The problem comes from the fact that those values are not constant during the whole life of the app. When the app starts, it's possible that the stage resizes, and thus you wouldn't be getting the right values.

First you could set those properties (I do this in 99% of my AS3 projects).

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Then add an event listener for stage resize, and in the handler write the stageWidth and stageHeight values to some vars you could then use to init Alternativa's camera. Or maybe wait for the event to trigger before setting up the camera.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, checkSize);
```

The handler

```
public function checkSize(e:Event):void {
    realWidth = stage.stageWidth;
    realHeight= stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Here is Adobe's documentation on the event, with examples on how to use it.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#event:resize